# Como escrever em duas variáveis do tipo unsigned char em c

Tags: c, scanf, entrada-de-dados

Estou tendo problema para escreverem duas variáveis do tipo unsigned char usando scanf, apenas o segundo valor fica salvo na variável, eu imagino que seja buffer com lixo tentei tratar e mesmo assim não obtive sucesso, segue minha tentativa alguém puder ajudar seria bacana

```
    unsigned char dividendo = 0;
    unsigned char divisor = 0;  
    unsigned char c = 0;

    // entradas do usuario 
    printf ("\nDenominador:\n>> ");
    scanf ("%d", &dividendo);
    printf ("\nDivisor:\n>> ");
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    scanf ("%d", &divisor);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está querendo ler variáveis do tipo unsigned char com scanf(), pois então use o especificador de formato %c, não o %d.

> eu imagino que seja buffer com lixo tentei tratar e mesmo assim não
> obtive sucesso

Não se trata de "lixo no buffer", até porque nada que resta de uma leitura é lixo.
scanf() não foi feita para ler dados inseridos via teclado, o usuário tem ao menos 105 teclas de liberdade, e a entrada pelo teclado não é nada formatada.
Se quer consumir todos os dados inseridos, o que pode fazer é ler e ignorar o '\n' digitado ao teclar Enter no final da leitura com o especificador %*c, veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    char b;

    printf("Numero: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &a);

    printf("Letra: ");
    scanf("%c%*c", &b);

    printf("%d\n%c\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Experimente sem o %*c e veja o '\n' sendo lido na segunda chamada da scanf(), impedindo o usuário de teclar o pretendido.